# What would happen if a Na'vi got his/her braid cut off?

Tags: avatar

Very simple question, but was there an in or out of universe answer for the question;

**What would happen if a Na'vi got his/her braid cut off?**

Would they die? Would it be like having your spinal cord severed and they would become paralysed? Or would it just mean they would not be able to link with the animals?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This was addressed in an [earlier version of the script](https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/jamescameronsavatar/images/f/f5/JamesCameronAVATAR.pdf/revision/latest?cb=20100826145259) (the "braid" is referred to as a "queue")

1. **It hurts. A lot**.
2. Cut off from their connection to [Eywa](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Eywa) and their fellow tribes-people, **the Na'vi will invariably commit suicide.**

> *WAINFLEET cuts Tsu’tey's queue off near the base. TSU’TEY SCREAMS in
>   agony, his nervous system exploding on overload. Grinning, Lyle holds
>   up the queue -- Tsu’tey's only connection to the world-consciousness
>   which is his life.*
>
> ... [later]
>
> **TSU’TEY:** *I can never ride again, or bond with my woman -- or hear the voice of Eywa. I can not lead the People. You will lead them,
>   Jakesully.*
>
> **JAKE:** *No. I’m not officer material.*
>
> **TSU’TEY:** *It is decided. Now do the duty of Olo’eyctan. Set my spirit free.*
>
> **JAKE:** *I’m not killing you.*
>
> **TSU’TEY:** *I am already dead.*

Comment: Much of this dialogue is found in the deleted scene from the DVD, but not the bit about having his queue cut off; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XuFg0aVt6o

Answer (score -1):

They wouldn't be able to ride, connect with the spirit tree, or even MATE! Not to mention, the pain is beyond human comparison- the na'vi's life is basically destroyed. Explaining why Tsu'tey embraced death after having his queue cut off.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. When answering questions like this though, please try and provide evidence from an official source to back your assertions up. Otherwise, how are we supposed to know if your answer accurately reflects what the filmmakers intended?